# How can we configure the Header of ant design table component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

We have requirement where we need to show 'Hide/Show' columns feature on the header of table and also we want to provide different color to the header of table in ant design. Can anyone help me how can we do this? I did not find any control to do it as header rendering is completely internal to component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `<Table.Column title={<...any react node...>}>` attribute in combination with ordinary CSS.

Comment: But correct me if I'm wrong but this will only effect the inner cell of the header, you can't use this method to set the color of the whole header?

Answer (score 19):

What I tried to resolve the background colour issue of header is overwrite the ant style class as below

```
thead[class*="ant-table-thead"] th{
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing or not. antd should provide the property on Table to configure the header style.

Is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: This is what I meant by "ordinary CSS" and it is certainly a correct way of doing it. There is no point in adding component level attributes to do the same thing that you can already do in CSS. It would just make the API unnecessarily bloated.

Comment: You can add your own `className="xxx"` if you don't want to override antd's classes.

Comment: @kalpana_pagariya Two years later and I am facing a [similar issue with configuring antd tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287043/) -- could you please elaborate on how you overwrote the antd style class?

Answer (score 2):

The solution offered by kalpana did not work for me. What did work (Ant V4.10.x) was this:

```
thead > tr > th {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Note that the `!important` setting is not required to make this work.

Similarly, if you want to target the cells of the table, you can use:

```
tbody > tr > td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```