# Add textbox filter between header and rows for antd table component

Tags: reactjs, antd

We have a requirement to show textbox filter on all columns between header and rows. Like click on the filter link above table, and show textbox below every column header. Is there any way to do with antd table component for reactjs?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question has basically the same answer as I gave you in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689128/how-can-we-configure-the-header-of-ant-design-table-component, which you have given me no credit for.

Comment: @JesperWe, Thanks for your help and really the suggestion which you have given me, it worked. I was little bit confuse here and now I am able to do this. I am new to UI and its stuff, so gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

Antd table has this feature to filter rows.

[Antd table filter documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-custom-filter-panel)

[image: Screenshot]