# How can I pass a className to the Header of a Table in antd / Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

With an Ant Design Table, I can pass a className to an arbitrary row using the `rowClassName` prop:

`rowClassName={(record, index) => index === 0 && 'headerClassName'}`

Is there any way to do this with the Header?

Comment: shooting... onHeaderRow className

Comment: repeated question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689128/how-can-we-configure-the-header-of-ant-design-table-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that CSS is quite tricky when it comes to styling tables, and the `antd Table` is built with regular HTML tables (with logical sugar on top). It isn't possible to pass a `className` to the header of a table with `antd`, but it also seems like that wouldn't be the most useful if we could.

Instead, the solution is to pass the `className` to the `Table` as a whole, and have CSS as follows in order to style the header.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'antd';
import { css } from 'react-emotion';

const tableCSS = css({
  margin: '40px 120px',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  '& table': {
    borderCollapse: 'collapse'
  },
  '& thead > tr > th': {
    backgroundColor: 'darkblue',
    color: 'white',
  },
  '& thead > tr': {
    borderWidth: '2px',
    borderColor: 'yellow',
    borderStyle: 'solid'
  }
});

const StyledTable = ({ data, columns }) => (
    <Table
      className={tableCSS}
      dataSource={data}
      columns={columns}
    />
);
```

*Note: You only need the `borderCollapse: 'collapse'` if you want a border that's around the header row.*

Answer (score 2):

For title key inside columns array of objects, change the string to react node..

We can make custom styling to header text using this way but it won't  solve the problem completely,

Just a sample

```
columns = [
    { title: <div style={{ background: "#01bcd4"  }}>Full Name:</div>, width: 100, dataIndex: 'name', key: 'name', fixed: 'left'},
      { title: <div style={{ background: "#01bcd4" }}>Presets:</div>, width: 100, dataIndex: 'age', key: 'age', fixed: 'left' }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here but you can define className on the `th` as follows. Make sure the className is near the top of the list or the columns will already be rendered before className can be applied.

```
const COLUMNS = [
  {
    title: "ID",
    className: "id",
    dataIndex: "id",
    dataType: "string",
    key: "id",
    searchable: true,
    sorter: makeValueSorter("id"),
  }, ...
```