# Creating a Matrix Table in React

Tags: reactjs, css-tables, antd

I need to create a matrix table in a react site.  In particular, I want to have a table with both vertical and horizontal headers, with a set of check-boxes for each cell.  Something like this (with check-boxes):

[image]

Now I am building this site using [Ant Design](https://ant.design/).  So, ideally I'd like to know how to do this using Ant Design.  But I am open to other solutions also (from other ui libraries, a component library - or something else that I have not thought of).

Any suggestions of how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried getting Ant Design Tables to look and function like a matrix - with no success.

Comment: He means that you should show what you have tried, questions without showing any effort typically downvoted

Comment: You can refer to my answer for the below question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395231/how-to-use-radio-groups-inside-antd-table/59440155#59440155